# Accelerometer API for Laptops

Tags: windows, accelerometer

Most IBM (and some Dell) laptops have built-in accelerometers to stop any moving parts during a sudden fall, but I was unable to find a standardised Windows API to access this data. I assume that each manufacturer would provide a driver to interface with the sensor.

1. Which popular laptop brands come standard with accelerometers accessible from an API and which libraries should I use to access the data?
2. Does an API* exist to abstract away the differences between different manufacturers? I am aware of the Windows 7 Sensor API, but I would like support for XP and earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most reputable notebook vendors have accelerometers to park the hard drive head if the notebook is accidentally dropped or is abruptly impacted by another object (i.e. when a certain acceleration threshold is exceeded). For example, my HP has its "HP 3D DriveGuard". However this technology is embedded low-level, it seems to work even if the OS is not loaded, so I suppose it is in the BIOS. I suppose that it is exposed just an ACPI way to enable or disable this technology. So, even on Windows 7 with standardized sensor APIs it is not accessible as a standard accelerometer like in a smartphone. Maybe in future if market demands it (but I don't think so).

Comment: :( I haven't found a generic solution yet either. Most providers don't expose this info yet.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work for all manufacturers, but after much searching (I've been wanting this feature myself), I found somebody who [wrote a driver wrapper](http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/hp-touchsmart-tm2-wacom/34370-automatic-display-rotation-protectsmart-accelerometer-10.html) for the accelerometers in HP laptops. If your laptop supports HP 3d DriveGuard or HP ProtectSmart, then this driver should let the accelerometer show up in the Windows sensor list.

- [32-bit driver installer](http://compugeeksoftware.com/software/downloads/tm2_accelerometer/ProtectSmartSensor%20%2832-bit%29.exe)
- [64-bit driver installer](http://compugeeksoftware.com/software/downloads/tm2_accelerometer/ProtectSmartSensor%20%2864-bit%29.exe)
- [example application](http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/attachments/hp-touchsmart-tm2-wacom/1326d1290428378-automatic-display-rotation-protectsmart-accelerometer-sensortest.zip) (with source!)

Tested it out on my HP laptop and it installed without a hitch. The example program works, but it's pretty slow to respond. I don't think this would work well for high-precision needs (such as gaming), but it might work if you just need some slower orientation data.

[image: windows control panel sensors]

Note that this works by exposing the accelerometer to the Windows sensors API. The sensors API provides a standard method of accessing any type of sensor regardless of the actual hardware installed. There's more information about the [Windows Sensor Platform on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463473).

Comment: Seems this doesn't work on HP 2540p with Windows 10.

Comment: Non-HTTPS download would make me nervous. From a quick look, no source code is available for the drivers. Installing such a privileged piece of software from an unofficial source, without trusted signature is quite a risk.

Comment: 32b version is unavailable: `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Comment: The example application + sources link requires registration. The [example application executable-only](http://compugeeksoftware.com/software/downloads/tm2_accelerometer/tm2%20accelerometer%20auto-rotate.exe) link in the forum post works without registration.