# Visual Basic hard disk acceleration sensor

Tags: .net, vb.net, accelerometer, hard-drive

Is there a way to detect the motion sensor in the hard disk with visual basic .net?
I know that hard discs has an acceleration sensor to turn the hard disk off when the computer falls from a height.

I have seen one example of this in a game using this sensor.
I want to detect the sensor so that my security program can alarm and email me if lets say someone nocks my computer to the floor while im gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939685/accelerometer-api-for-laptops), it appears the hard disk acceleration sensor is just not available at the OS level.

That said, some laptops have their own accelerometers that can be accessed [programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318936.aspx) in Windows 7. This is a lower-level API, however, and not directly mapped in .NET that I'm aware of. [This blog entry](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/04/02/windows-7-sensor-and-location-net-interop-sample-library.aspx) helps walk you through some of the issues you'll encounter using the API in .NET